# Как посмотреть настройки smtp postfix

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, postfix

Мне для настройки smtp транспорта нужны настройки 
smtps://username:password@smtp.example.com/?pool=true

Postfix я установил. Где мне взять эти настройки ?

Уточнение:

У меня отправка почты на node.js

```
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        sendmail: true,
        newline: 'windows',
        logger: false,
        path: - ?
    });
    let message = {
        from: 'z_sergey_v@mail.ru',
        to: 'z_sergey_v@mail.ru',
        bcc: 'z_sergey_v@mail.ru',
        subject: 'Nodemailer is unicode friendly ✔',
        text: 'Hello to myself!',
        html:
            '<p><b>Hello</b> to myself <img src="cid:z_sergey_v@mail.ru"/></p>' +
            '<p>Here\'s a nyan cat for you as an embedded attachment:<br/><img src="cid:z_sergey_v@mail.ru"/></p>',
        // An array of attachments
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: 'notes.txt',
                content: 'Some notes about this e-mail',
                contentType: 'text/plain' // optional, would be detected from the filename
            },

            // Binary Buffer attachment
            {
                filename: 'image.png',
                content: Buffer.from(
                    'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD/' +
                    '//+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4U' +
                    'g9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC',
                    'base64'
                ),
                cid: 'z_sergey_v@mail.ru' // should be as unique as possible
            }
        ]
    };
    let info = await transporter.sendMail(message);
    console.log('Message sent successfully as %s', info.messageId);
    res.end( info.messageId );
});
```

Почта не отправляется, надо указать путь к sendmail.
Почта из консоли отправляется. Установлен postfix

```
echo "Email body text" | sudo mail -s "Email subject line" xxxyyy@xxxxyyy.ru -aFrom:xxxx@xxxxx.ru
```

Как мне посмотреть параметры mail программы ? откуда берутся настройки для отпраки ?

Comment: видимо, речь про «смартхост»

Comment: Я уточнение написал, весь вечер вчера сидел читал. И у меня оправка заработала пока настраивал, но я это не заметил сразу и убил весь конфиг. Сейчас повторить не получается. ))

Comment: `smtp://127.0.0.1/` и всё наверно

Comment: Только вот за `from: 'z_sergey_v@mail.ru'` вас любой почтовик отправит в спам, потому что вы пытаетесь выдать себя за сервер mail.ru, но вы ведь явно не mail.ru, да?

Comment: Ну это я разбираюсь. Читаю сейчас.
У меня нода сейчас выдаёт такую ошибку

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.1.1:587

Какэтот порт открыть для прослушивания ?

Comment: Не нужно этот порт открывать, используйте порт 25

Comment: Где можно посмотреть  smtpConfig  который использует программа для линукса mail ?

    var smtpConfig = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 587
        // secure: true, // use SSL
        // auth: {
        //     user: 'user@myDomain.com',
        //     pass: 'pass@pass'
        // }
    };

Comment: Не существует никакого smtpConfig, она просто подключается к 127.0.0.1 на порту 25, пишет туда письмо по протоколу smtp и всё. Используйте порт 25 и secure:false и никакого auth

Comment: До меня ваши слова дошли через два часа. я тупой. спасибо.